# WebView2 Wpf does not update page

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml, webview2

I'm writing a WPF application in C#. Into this application is shown a web page.
I defined the following code:

XAML:

```
<wv2:WebView2 Name="WebView"
    Width="350"
        Height="550"
        Source = "{Binding url}"
/>
```

ViewModel:

```
url = new Uri("https://192.11.2.33/test/index.html");
```

It works, but if I edit the index.html at next start of the application the page is not updated.  I suppose that the old page is stored somewhere in cache. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is url a property or a field?  Does it implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  Your code shown does not really show anything.

Comment: About your first question "url" is a property. About your second question I didn't implement the INotifyChanged. I cannot write other code because there's no other code... Why  should I write a INotifyChanged? As I wrote "at next start of the application the page is not updated"... I don't need to update the page while the application is running but just at start of it.